# Java identify an Exception precisely

Tags: java, exception

In Java we can catch exceptions of a certain type:

```
try{ 
    // Code that does IO like download a file...
}catch(IOException ioe){
    ioe.printStackTrace();
    // handle ioe
}catch(SomeOtherException soe){
    // handle soe 
}
```

Now, there can by many causes to an Exception, in this case, the `IOException` can be:

```
java.io.IOException: Illegal character in path at index.....
```

from a specific library or some other like:

```
java.io.IOException: Stream closed ...
```

If something went wrong with a `Stream`

Now, my question is, how do I determine what kind of `IOException` happened?

How do I distinguish between a `Stream closed` and `Illegal character in path at index...`?

Of course I can just check the String of the exception message but I don't think it's the best way since the underlying library/implementation can change the message string.

**EDIT:**

`e.getClass()` in this case returns `java.io.IOException` for almost everything...

I guess the library throws their own `IOException` while discarding any original `Exception`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The fact that the `printStackTrace` printed

```
java.io.IOException: Stream closed ...
//      ^^^^^^^^^^^
```

and

```
java.io.IOException: Illegal character in path at index.....
//      ^^^^^^^^^^^
```

means the `Exception` is of type `IOException`. There isn't a more specific subtype you can use here.

There is no way in this case. They decided to use the same `Exception` type for both (and more) of those reasons. You won't be able to distinguish them with different `catch` statements. You'll need to check their message.

If the `Exception` has a `cause`, you'll have to see if there's a distinguishing type and rethrow it. If you're lucky, you might be able to catch a more specific type of `Exception`.

Comment: I've upvoted you back because this is the only answer that sees the `IOEeception` and knows it's a concrete type. I don't know why would somebody downvote you in the first place...

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels The `printStackTrace` method depends on the `toString` method. The `Throwable` implementation prints the class name with `getClass().getName()`. So unless a `StreamClosedException` overrid its `toString` to return the `IOException` class name, the concrete type is `IOException`.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels None needed. :)

Comment: the cause is null so I guess the only way is to do a `String.contains()` for `Illegal character` for now...

Comment: @tom Temporarily, you can do that. however the message is specific to the implementation. If it changes, you'll have to do the same. What kind of different handling are you going to do?

Comment: The `Illegal character` exception is something that I can potentially fix because the error is on my side; anything else I'm just gonna show  log and show an error message to the user

Answer (score 4):

You can catch the exception differently since `IOException` is a top hierarchy of sub exceptions

From [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/package-tree.html):

```
java.io.IOException 
    java.io.CharConversionException
    java.io.EOFException
    java.io.FileNotFoundException
    java.io.InterruptedIOException
    java.io.ObjectStreamException
       java.io.InvalidClassException
       java.io.InvalidObjectException
       java.io.NotActiveException
       java.io.NotSerializableException
       java.io.OptionalDataException
       java.io.StreamCorruptedException
       java.io.WriteAbortedException
    java.io.SyncFailedException
    java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException
    java.io.UTFDataFormatException
    java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException
    java.io.UTFDataFormatException
```

Comment: The concrete type of the exceptions in OP's case seem to be `IOException`. More specific subtypes won't help.

Comment: Yep, I've made an edit please check the updated question

Answer (score 2):

When a library raises a too-generic exception (as, it seems, you're running into here with `IOException`) you unfortunately don't have a lot of good options - essentially this is poor design on the library's part.  Ideally, you should file a bug or submit a pull request for the offending library, but this may not be possible or feasible.

However all is not lost.  First and foremost, it is possible the library is actually giving you more information than you think, by including with the generic `IOException` the underlying cause via [`Throwable.getCause()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Throwable.html#getCause()).  This is a robust way to provide more detailed debugging information while exposing a single `Exception` for normal handling.  If this library follows this practice, you can do something like:

```
catch(IOException e) {
  Throwable cause = e.getCause();
  if(cause != null && cause instanceof URISyntaxException) {
    System.err.println("Bad URI");
  } else {
    System.err.println("Other IOException");
  }
}
```

Of course, turning what some Googling suggests is a `URISyntaxException` into an `IOException` isn't a terribly good design in the first place (an invalid URI is certainly not an IO issue) so I wouldn't be surprised if the library is simply calling something like `throw new IOException(e.getMessage())` and discarding the original, meaning unfortunately all you have to go on is the exception's message.

Like you note, parsing exception messages isn't a terribly great idea.  Ideally, you should wrap this poor behavior into a helper method so that you can easily refactor it out once the library is improved, and detect if anything unexpected occurs and address it.  Consider:

```
public void doOperation(arguments) throws IOException, URISyntaxException {
  try {
    BadLibrary.doOperation(arguments);
  } catch(IOException e) {
    if(e.getMessage().startsWith("Illegal character")) {
      throw new URISyntaxException("Uknown", e.getMessage());
    } else if(e.getMessage().startsWith("Stream closed")) {
      throw e;
    } else {
      // note we include the cause here
      throw new RuntimeException("Unexpected exception from BadLibrary", e);
    }
  }
}
```

With this compartmentalization you only have to do this unpleasant check in one place, and can be *reasonably* confident you'll detect unexpected changes to the underlying library, rather than silently ignoring them.